# Getting HTML markup from TinyMCE?

Tags: tinymce, rich-text-editor

I am new to TinyMCE and I was wondering if TinyMCE or any RTE had the ability to access the HTML markup. I've looked at methods like getContent() but that to me seems like it only gets the data inside the HTML rather than the full HTML itself.

Comment: What do you mean by "gets the data inside the HTML rather than the full HTML itself."?  That API is precisely how you extract the content from TinyMCE.

Comment: Oh so does getContent() give back pure HTML markup?

Comment: It does indeed - try it to see what you get.

Comment: @MichaelFromin Thank you!